# Случайная запись из БД

Tags: база-данных, mysql

Скажите, если в БД MySQL есть 3 записи (там ссылки на картинки), как надо выбрать случайную из этих 3-х и вывести это в теге `<img></img>`?

Answer (score 2):

здесь почитайте
[Selecting random record from MySQL database table.](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/)

Comment: Спасибо товарищ :)